# multi-select-react not working MultiSelectReact component

Tags: reactjs

```
import  MultiSelectReact  from 'multi-select-react';

multiSelect:[];

<MultiSelectReact 
  options={this.state.multiSelect}
  optionClicked={this.optionClicked}
  selectedBadgeClicked={this.selectedBadgeClicked}
  selectedOptionsStyles={selectedOptionsStyles}
  optionsListStyles={optionsListStyles} 
/>

optionClicked(optionsList) {
 this.setState({ multiSelect: optionsList });
}
selectedBadgeClicked(optionsList) {
 this.setState({ multiSelect: optionsList });
}
```

I tried this component with the above code.But, It shows empty dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data in the array :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MultiSelectReact from 'multi-select-react';

class MultiSelect extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      multiSelect: [{ label: 'first', value: true }, { label: 'second' }],
    };
  }

  render() {
    const selectedOptionsStyles = {
      color: '#3c763d',
      backgroundColor: '#dff0d8',
    };
    const optionsListStyles = {
      backgroundColor: '#fcf8e3',
      color: '#8a6d3b',
    };
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '200px' }}>
        <MultiSelectReact
          options={this.state.multiSelect}
          optionClicked={this.optionClicked.bind(this)}
          selectedBadgeClicked={this.selectedBadgeClicked.bind(this)}
          selectedOptionsStyles={selectedOptionsStyles}
          optionsListStyles={optionsListStyles}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  optionClicked(optionsList) {
    console.log(
      'here the lib adds value false to the selected item',
      optionsList
    );
    this.setState({ multiSelect: optionsList });
  }
  selectedBadgeClicked(optionsList) {
    console.log(
      'here the lib adds value true to the selected item',
      optionsList
    );
    this.setState({ multiSelect: optionsList });
  }
}

export default MultiSelect;


// then use it by importing and calling <MultiSelect />
```

**Edit:** you need also to add ids for each option in the array:

```
  [
    { label: 'first', value: true, id: 1 },
    { label: 'second', id: 2 },
  ],
```

- and i think you should use the [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) component instead.